# Running S3cmd from PHP Script not working

Tags: amazon-s3, s3cmd

I want to use `s3cmd` from my PHP script. Everything is working from shell but same not working from my PHP script.

```
shell_exec('s3cmd --config=/root/s3cmd.conf ls');
```

this is not working, and then i gave full path to my s3cmd installation

```
shell_exec('/usr/sbin/s3cmd --config=/root/s3cmd.conf ls');
```

Not working in PHP script but the same is working in command,

The PHP file which is calling the shell_exec is in webroot.

Might be the problem that s3cmd is configured as a root user and i am running from PHP which is www-data. if this is the problem how can i create config file for www-data.

Help me what i am doing wrong.

Thanks

**EDIT**
I am using S3cmd. To run commands in my cron script. cron Script is a PHP script. The user running the cron is web11 and the s3cmd is configured using the root user.

so when i run s3cmd using shell_exec() in my PHP script it fails. But when i run in shell it works fine.

## s3cmd ls

This works fine. as i am login using root user.

i tried to run it using runuser command

## runuser -l root -c "s3cmd ls"

This works fine and displays list of buckets. But when i run using

## runuser -l root -c "s3cmd ls"

This does not work. I tried by giving full path of the s3cmd

## /usr/bin/s3cmd ls

this works in shell but not in my PHP script.

I changed permissions 777 for the php script and made root the owner of that user. but still does not work.

How can i run s3cmd from PHP script. ? i am on amazon Ec2 Instance.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the [AWS SDK for PHP](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/)? You can have the same functionality using the [S3Client.listObjects()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_listObjects) method

Comment: Actually i want to perform tasks in the cronjob, like get size of the all objects, and deleting objects.

Answer (score 0):

> shell_exec('s3cmd --config=/root/s3cmd.conf ls');

What might be missing here is the target of the S3 command "ls" ?!

It's working fine in PHP scripts like this :

```
exec("/usr/bin/s3cmd --config=.s3cfg info s3://YOUR-BUCKET/YOUR-FILE 2> /dev/null", $s3output, $s3return);

// switch due to return code (of shell !)
if($s3return == "0"){
    echo "my file exists";
}
else {
    echo "Error Code : " . $s3return;
}
```

This asumes, you ran "s3cmd --configure" successfully.